# R: Why does my heat map look differently depending on whether I sort my data first?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I make a heatmap in R that shows the dependency of a variable (Corona misinformation Score) on two other variables (Indifference Score and Rigidity Score). I do not understand why ordering my data according to the Corona misinformation score makes a difference for how the heatmap looks.

Here is the code I use to generate the graph:

```
dset %>%
  arrange(Mean_Corona) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Mean_Rigidity, y=Mean_Indifference, fill = Mean_Corona)) +
  geom_tile(alpha=0.8) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") +
  ylab("Indifference Score") +
  xlab("Rigidity Score") +
  labs(color="Corona Misinformation Score") +
  theme(
    legend.position="bottom", 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey70", size = 0.2),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

This is what the graph looks like:

[image: Heatmap with arrange]

If I run the same code but remove the second line (arrange(Mean_Corona) %>%), the heatmap looks instead like this:

[image: Heatmap without arrange]

If I order the data for the same variable in descending order, the heatmap looks different again. What I don't understand is why ordering rows in the dataset should make any difference to how the graph looks. Should not the shading of each tile just be determined by the average Corona Misinformation score for people with that score? I am stuck because I am not sure what the more accurate way of displaying my data is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will notice the plots have all the tiles in the same *position* but that some tiles have different colours. You are quite right that the ordering of `Mean_Corona` shouldn't make a difference, but that is true **only if the position of each tile is unique**. If you have multiple values for each tile position and you sort for `Mean_Corona`, then the lower value tiles are plotted first, and the higher values are plotted *on top of* the lower values. If you reverse that ordering, the higher value tiles will be obscured by the lower value tiles.

We can see this more clearly if we create a small dummy data set with 8 unique tiles but only 4 unique tile positions:

```r
dset <- data.frame(Mean_Corona = 1:8,
                   Mean_Indifference = rep(c(0.5, 1.5), 4),
                   Mean_Rigidity = rep(c(0.5, 1.5), each = 4))
```

So let's plot this with the original data frame, which happens to be sorted by `Mean_Corona` already:

```
dset %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Mean_Rigidity, y=Mean_Indifference, fill = Mean_Corona)) +
  geom_tile(alpha=0.8) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") +
  ylab("Indifference Score") +
  xlab("Rigidity Score") +
  labs(color="Corona Misinformation Score") +
  theme(
    legend.position="bottom", 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey70", size = 0.2),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Now we plot with the values in descending order. Here we see that the lower values have been plotted over the higher values:

```
dset %>%
  arrange(-Mean_Corona) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Mean_Rigidity, y=Mean_Indifference, fill = Mean_Corona)) +
  geom_tile(alpha=0.8) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") +
  ylab("Indifference Score") +
  xlab("Rigidity Score") +
  labs(color="Corona Misinformation Score") +
  theme(
    legend.position="bottom", 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey70", size = 0.2),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

One possible solution here is to group by both the indifference and rigidity scores, then take the average of the tiles at that position. That will ensure you have a single tile at each location that better reflects the relationship between variables.

```
dset %>%
  group_by(Mean_Rigidity, Mean_Indifference) %>%
  summarise(Mean_Corona = mean(Mean_Corona)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Mean_Rigidity, y=Mean_Indifference, fill = Mean_Corona)) +
  geom_tile(alpha=0.8) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "RdYlGn") +
  ylab("Indifference Score") +
  xlab("Rigidity Score") +
  labs(color="Corona Misinformation Score") +
  theme(
    legend.position="bottom", 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey70", size = 0.2),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Allen, thank you for your great response. I had been assuming that a heat map would not just plot tiles on top of one another, but for each tile compute the mean value for observations pertaining to that tile and then color the tile correspondingly. I now understand that a heatmap works essentially like a scatterplot: if there is more than one observation, it maters in which order the observations are added.

Comment: I would still like to color each tile according to the mean Corona misinformation score pertaining to observations relevant to that tile. I have experimented with the group_by function, but I could not really crack how to do it -- just grouping does not cut it. I expect I need to generate a new variable after the grouping, but I cannot quite rap my head around it. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @MarcoMeyer see my update. The third method does what you describe in your first comment, and emulates how you thought geom_tile should have worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the alpha, because the order defines in which way the tiles are plotted over each other.

Best regards
Roel

Comment: Thank you Roel! Just removing the Alpha does not solve the issue unfortunately.